# Storing encryption keys on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app (minimum Android version is 5.0 - API Level 21) that stores data in a local database via RoomDatabase. However, the data needs to be encrypted for which I used SQL Cipher. My question is what is the safest way to store the key used for SQL Cipher. So far, I have two options and a major 'concern' for both of them:

1. Using the Android Keystore - however my biggest concern here is whether a user with root privileges can access the Keystore?
2. Using NDK to create a key - from what I've seen the file can easily be decompiled and the key can be extracted somewhat easily.

The app itself is simple so asking the user for a pin/password would not be a way to solve this. The same applies for getting a key from a server since the app doesn't require constant Internet access.

Comment: "My question is what is the safest way to store the key used for SQL Cipher" -- in the user's head. "The app itself is simple so asking the user for a pin/password would not be a way to solve this" -- sure it is. "whether a user with root privileges can access the Keystore?" -- it's more that they could get it from your app process, between when you get the key from the keystore and hand it to SQLCipher. This is not easy but is doable. "from what I've seen the file can easily be decompiled and the key can be extracted somewhat easily" -- hardcoded keys are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebase may be the answer because:

1. It does not need constant network access it will cache the data.
2. The saved key is not in your app, it is in the web or inside the cache of Firebase service.
3. It is simple to setup.

You can use one of these products to save your key at Firebase:
Cloud Firestore, Cloud Functions or Cloud Storage.

Or you may use Firebase Authentication instead of saving key.